# how to style Mui AutoComplete endAdornment icon

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to change the color and size of downwards icon for the Mui Autocomplete, this is what I've tried but it's not working:

```
<Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="search-bar"
      options={data}
      sx={{
        width: "100%",
        flex: 1,
        "& .MuiAutocomplete-root": {
          padding: "0px",
        },
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          InputLabelProps={{
            sx: { color: "#12efc8" },
          }}
          name="subCategory"
          type="text"
          sx={{
            width: "100%",
            input: {
              color: "#12efc8",
            },
            maxWidth: "inherit",
            "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
              height: "49px",

              "&.focus": {
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
              },
            },
            "& .MuiFormControl-root": {
              "& .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment": {
                color: "white",
                scale: 2,
              },
            },
          }}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Add Sub-Category"
        />
      )}
    />
```

I've also tried moving the following code up to the styling of the parent element (AutoComplete), but it didn't work either:

```
      "& .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment": {
        color: "white",
        scale: 2,
      },
```

Apparently, the class for the icon is a subclass of .MuiInputBase-root, not sure how since it's called .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you're right - *Apparently, the class for the icon is a subclass of `.MuiInputBase-root`, not sure how since it's called `.MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment`.*

It will set style to endAdornment. However, if you want to change the color and size of the downward icon for the Mui Autocomplete, you need to add `MuiIconButton-root` or `MuiSvgIcon-root`.

For example:

```
"& .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment .MuiIconButton-root": {
  color: "red",
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
},
```

or

```
"& .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
  color: "red",
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
},
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-hooks-vp5j9t?file=/Demo.js).